# MySQL vs SQL Server Express (Compare Free DBMS)

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-express

I am searching for a comparison table between MySQL and SQL Server Express.

Comparisons should include...

- Usage limit
- Tools (management/dev/backup/monitoring/...)
- "simultaneous connection"

It's for my company, I need to know what should I install.

It's for migrating from access db

if you have opinion, suggestions,....

Thank you

Comment: Why not take PostgreSQL into account as well? In terms of SQL features it's much closer to SQL Server (in fact that are several areas where it's better)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft provides a comparison between MySQL, SQL Server Express, and SQL Server Enterprise. Just go to http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/competitor-compare.aspx and pick MySQL in the dropdown box. Take it with a grain of salt, as the information is provided by Microsoft, the maker of SQL Server.

If you go to http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx and click on SQL Server Express, you will see just how restrictive the limitations are:
Express will run only using one CPU, will only use up to 1 GB of RAM, and will allow you to have a database up to 10 GB only.

If you do not want to face all those restrictions you should go with MySQL. MySQL provides InnoDB engine which is fully ACID compliant, you can have online backups by using mysqldump with correct options with InnoDB tables or by using Xtrabackup from Percona. I would recommend going with Linux for MySQL as it is usually a more stable platform and gives you more flexibility since many tools for MySQL are written for Linux. MySQL has replication and high availability if you go with MySQL Cluster.

Comment: Note: later versions of SQL Server Express / Compact / CE support larger database sizes and other higher limits.

Answer (score 10):

I will be totally honest with you. While MySQL works fine in Windows, I would not recommend it for any Enterprise use in Windows.

You should go with SQL Server Express because you will have a database that works great in Windows for Free. Should your company fully commit to Enterprise Database usage, [you could simply upgrade to SQL Server (different advanced versions)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/how-can-i-tell-if-my-sql-server-db-performance-is-hardware-limited/3278#3278).

If you are going for moderate budget, go with MySQL, BUT SWITCH TO Linux. High Availability solutions fit Linux and Unix, not Windows.

Comment: MySQL 5.5 does quite well on Windows. As the question is about migration from Access: It can't be worse ;-) (while Access has some nice use cases)

Comment: tank, I was think the same by using sql express.
My idea was starting with sql express. test migration of db and application. test express option. and if they want more (or I see they need more), I will ask for standard or enterprise. 

I dont go on standard now because of all company politics, that will take minimum of 2weeks to get a paid version.

my interrogation is about db backup, did express have something?

Comment: with SQL Express, you can easily build BACKUP scripts by right-click BACKUP in SSMS, and then you can hit the SCRIPT button and then you can easily use this script in a stored procedure, or via the command line, etc.  I love SQL Server backup, and mySQL backup terrifies me.. I just don't want to have to troubleshoot 40mb mySQL backups.. and I've never had much trouble with SQL Server backup / restore. To be honest, in 12 years, I've had ONE backup that wouldn't restore because it had a CRC error. That was my own fault for transferring large BAK file over dialup without compression :)

Comment: on the mySQL side, I'm ALWAYS having scripts fail.. I just think that SQL Server backups are ten times as enterprise ready than mySQL.. MySQL backups are just a bunch of scripts, It really disgusts me, I just want something that *JUST*WORKS*. I abhor SQL files that are 40mb when you have to troubleshoot that much SQL, it's just impossible.

Answer (score 4):

[Comparison of relational database management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems) wiki contains feature comparisons for many RDBMSs.

Although SQL Server Express is not listed in the wiki, SQL Server is. You will have to look up Microsoft's comparison of what is different between SQL Server and SQL Server Express.

Comment: I look for this (different between SQL Server and SQL Server Express.) but theres so much thing that I dont understand.
I look at http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx, compare so many thing. but what I need

I only have 100 people here, maybe some software, but rarely use more than 1 at a time.

if you have a better/more basic user compare list, that can be very helpful.